# How to use if/else inside useEffect() while dispatching an action in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My redux related imports are as follows -

source: https://github.com/theairbend3r/pokedex

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"

import {
  fetchPokemonNameUrl,
  NUMBER_OF_POKEMON,
  selectorPokemon,
} from "./pokemonCardsSlice"


const dispatch = useDispatch()
const pokemonList = useSelector(selectorPokemon)
```

I have a `useEffect` block as follows -

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl())
  }, [dispatch])
```

What I want to do -

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (pokemonList.length !== NUMBER_OF_POKEMON) {
      return dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl())
    }
  }, [dispatch])
```

But when I do this, I get a warning -

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'pokemonList.length'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to add pokemonList within the dependency array ...i.e. `[dispatch, pokemonList]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `pokemonList` to [the dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) as suggested, your callback depends on the value of `pokemonList` (`.length`) which may change.

When `pokemonList` will be updated, the callback will run again with the updated `length`.

Also, you don't need to return from `useEffect` as [it is for cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect).

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (pokemonList.length !== NUMBER_OF_POKEMON) {
    dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl());
  }
}, [dispatch,pokemonList]);
```

---

**Edit:** Seems like `fetchPokemonNameUrl` implemented as middleware, you can rewrite as something like:

```
const fetchPokemonNameUrl = async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.get(URL);
  const data = response.data.results;

  data.map(async (poke) => {
    const responseDetails = await axios.get(poke.url);

    let tempDetails = {
      name: responseDetails.data.species.name,
      baseExperience: responseDetails.data.base_experience,
      height: responseDetails.data.height,
      weight: responseDetails.data.weight,
      type: responseDetails.data.types[0].type.name,
      sprites: responseDetails.data.sprites.front_default,
    };

    dispatch(getData(tempDetails));
  });
};

// And call it:
useEffect(() => {
  if (pokemonList.length !== NUMBER_OF_POKEMON) {
    fetchPokemonNameUrl(dispatch);
  }
}, [dispatch,pokemonList]);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but then my app won't load now. In the console, I get the following - `Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:`

Can you please have a look at the code here => https://github.com/theairbend3r/pokedex/tree/master/src/features/explore ?

The relevant files are `pokemonCardsSlice.js` and `PokemonCards.js`.

Comment: `fetchPokemonNameUrl` is not an action its a middleware. You can't call it like this

Comment: See [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)

Comment: do you wanna try @dennis Vash? - https://github.com/theairbend3r/pokedex - would prefer not to be downvoted any further

Comment: How do we call it then? Like, the app works If I do this => `  useEffect(() => {dispatch(fetchPokemonNameUrl())}, [dispatch])`.

Comment: See related link, or fetch it within the `useEffect`, there are enough examples how its done.

Comment: I tried out your edited version @DennisVash; but now the app only fetched a single pokemon (and not 10). I have a couple follow up questions about your edited code - when you say `fetchPokemonNameUrl` is implemented as a middleware, what do you mean? And how is your implementation different? (it looks the same as mine except for the try-catch blocks). Sorry if my questions are too basic, I'm new to reactjs/redux. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I can only answer on **specific** questions, you may have other bugs that I don't aware. You can read about middlewares in redux docs and read about how to use `useEffect` in react docs. Please ask another question with a specific problem as the original question is solved.